# Android Watch: make the ambient card scheme the default

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watchface

Is there a way to set cards to use their ambient color scheme in interactive mode?

Comment: SO won't let me create a 3-character answer, so I'm putting it here instead: **No.**

Comment: @String Figures...That would be too awesome. Thank you.